# Does a OUTER-JOIN always divide the query in two parts, leaving the part on the right empty if not complete in Progress?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to do an OUTER-JOIN in progress using [this](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000035574) page as inspiration. My code is as follows

```
OPEN QUERY qMovto
FOR EACH movto-estoq
WHERE movto-estoq.lote BEGINS pc-lote
AND movto-estoq.it-codigo BEGINS pc-it-codigo
AND movto-estoq.dt-trans >=  pd-data1
AND movto-estoq.dt-trans <=  pd-data2
AND movto-estoq.cod-emitente = pi-cod-emitente,
    EACH item OUTER-JOIN
    WHERE movto-estoq.it-codigo = item.it-codigo,
        EACH item-cli OUTER-JOIN
        WHERE item-cli.item-do-cli BEGINS pc-item-cli
        AND movto-estoq.cod-emitente = item-cli.cod-emitente
        AND movto-estoq.it-codigo = item-cli.it-codigo
        AND movto-estoq.un = item-cli.unid-med-cli,    
            EACH nota-fiscal OUTER-JOIN
            WHERE movto-estoq.nro-docto = nota-fiscal.nr-nota-fis
            BY movto-estoq.dt-trans DESCENDING BY movto-estoq.hr-trans DESCENDING.
```

The problem that is happening is when 1 element in null, all the other elements that are in the OUTER-JOIN are appearing as null as well, even though they are not null. Is there a better way to write this code? Should I put 'LEFT' before the OUTER-JOIN? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

To make your example easier, consider making it work from ABL dojo. The following code:

```
define temp-table ttone
   field ii as int
   .

define temp-table tttwo
   field ii as int
   field cc as char
   .

create ttone. ttone.ii = 1.
create ttone. ttone.ii = 2.
create tttwo. tttwo.ii = 2. tttwo.cc = "inner".
create tttwo. tttwo.ii = 3. tttwo.cc = "orphan".

define query q for ttone, tttwo.
open query q 
    for each ttone, 
    each tttwo outer-join where tttwo.ii = ttone.ii.
    
get first q.
do while available ttone:
   message ttone.ii tttwo.cc.
   get next q.
end.
```

Can be run from https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=600f40919585066c219797ed

As you can see, this results in :

```
1 ?
2 inner
```

The join which is not available is shown as *unknown*. The value of the outer part of the join *is* shown.

Since you do not show how you are getting an unknown value for everything, maybe you are concatenating the unknown values?